# xerces Xpath - search node from another node

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing, xerces, xerces2-j

I have the follows XML:

```
    <ONIXMessage>
        <Product>
            <RecordReference>9786071502131</RecordReference>
            <RecordReference>9786071502131</RecordReference>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <RecordReference>9786071502131</RecordReference>
        </Product>
    </ONIXMessage>
```

And the follows java code:

```
    Element ONIXmessage = document.getDocumentElement();
    products = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(ONIXmessage, "/ONIXMessage/Product");

    for(int i = 0;i < products.getLength();i++) {  
        Node product = products.item(i);

        NodeList prova = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(ONIXmessage, "/ONIXMessage/Product/RecordReference");
        System.out.println(prova.getLength());

        NodeList prova2 = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(product, "/ONIXMessage/Product/RecordReference");
        System.out.println(prova2.getLength()); 
    }
```

This code returns: 3 3 3 3

I think this code should return 3 2 3 1 because the "prova" variable contains all "RecordReference" nodes of the document, and "prova2" only contains the specific "RecordReference" nodes of only one product node.

How I can use XPATH to get only the nodes of a particular product?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to [`XPathAPI#selectNodeList`](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI.html#selectNodeList%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20java.lang.String%29) is the context for the XPath expression.

Passing the `product` variable is reasonable and correct, but your XPath query is wrong: a slash `/` in the beginning of an expression denominates the root node *of the current context*, which in this case is the `<ONIXMessage/>` element.

Instead, start at the current context which is represented by the dot `.`. Remember your new expression is starting at this context, so your new XPath would be `./RecordReference`. You could even ommit the `./`, but I prefer adding these two characters making the query easier to read and understand:

```
NodeList prova2 = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(product, "./RecordReference");
```